# How to execute instructors in order with ruby net ssh channel?

Tags: ruby, ssh, asynchronous

As the net-ssh manual book says the method "exec" executes a command asynchronously on channel.http://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-3.html#s6

But when I hope to execute some instructors in order, for example:

```
def work(session, instructor )
  session.open_channel do |channel|
    channel.on_data do |ch, data|
      puts data.strip
    end
    channel.exec instructor
  end
end

Net::SSH.start( 'host' ) do |session|
  work session, "touch a.file" 
  work session, "mv a.file b.file"
  work session, "rm b.file"
  session.loop
end
```

Executing a command asynchronously really makes such code doesn't work.

Can anybody help me to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [sync shell service](http://net-ssh.github.io/ssh/v1/chapter-5.html#s4) for it, do something like:

```
Net::SSH.start( 'localhost' ) do |session|
  shell = session.shell.sync
  shell.touch 'a.file'
  shell.mv 'a.file', 'b.file'
  shell.send_command("rm", 'b.file')
  shell.exit
end
```

or just organize the commands on-a-line:

```
work session, "touch a.file; mv a.file b.file; rm b.file"
```

Comment: What if the command I want to exec is not a basic shell command? I think the second way is OK. But it is not clear if my commands is very  long.  Thanks.

Comment: @wonderflow the document say not that the shell is only bash, I believe that is just the default remove shell.

Comment: @МалъСкрылевъ - I have a small issue with ssh connection state. Please help me - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28799593/unix-commands-work-on-server-but-not-in-ruby-ssh-session thanks.